# How to build API handle Concurrency Request

Tags: asp.net, api, concept

I have been develop API using asp.net with C# back-end code.
i would like to understand more concept how to make the API support more client to call,
It's because i want to have experience the same that able to like twitter.

Do you guys have any article like, 
how to make the API able to handle concurrency request.
what kind of server that support at least 100 million request / hrs.
Is there any limitation that .Net able to request concurrency per second?

Regards,
Herman

Comment: Hi, you have been giving a large number, like 100 x E6 per hour, that's quite a number, however why do you think IIS is unable to handle this? I think you should design your backend code in a careful way so to be very outperforming and the web server will handle clients concurrency for you, you should not reimplement this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look to build a horizontally scalable solution in order to handle large traffic volumes using web farms. Hosting providers like Amazon/Rackspace/Azure offer great Cloud based infrastructures for doing this if you don't want to concern yourself with the effort and expensive of building your own farm.

There's some [useful information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650667.aspx) here about general scaling considerations.

Obviously this is **not** an alternative to optimising your code, and there are also many considerations when building sites to support concurrently **before** you scale, including correct use of double-checked locking where appropriate and implementing sensible caching based on your requirements. This will go a long way to supporting many requests, particularly if the content is static.